# Making a printable half sphere with a cutout in it for 3D printing

Tags: edges, 3d-printing, knife-tool

[image: Knife Project cut out]
I made a half sphere which prints nicely. The sphere is to be used as a stencil for marking your golf ball.

I used the Knife Project to cutout the F.  This however created a lot of non-manifolded edges, which are not printable.

How can I cut out the shape and still preserve the mesh?

Comment: so once you've deleted the face you can extrude your object to give it thickness, or give it a Solidify modifier then apply, and it should work, no? If there's already thickness you could even use a boolean...

Comment: Worked just like you said. Just added the solidify modifier.  Please make it an answer so I can check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've deleted the face you can extrude your object to give it thickness, or give it a *Solidify* modifier then apply. If there's already thickness you could extrude your F and use a *Boolean* modifier on your half-sphere.